# Internal space near full but shouldn't be and not according to other stats

Tags: troubleshooting

So yesterday i was seeing how many apps i have installed and i noticed this...according to which only 248 MB is free. Which looks wrong to me too.

[image]

But that is not the case according to storage analyser app...and which i also think should be the case as i know what i am installing and keeping eye on space a certain app takes.

[image]

...you can also see it's the same thing (as storage analyser app) in my computer!

[image]

So how come..? is it a problem, and what can i do to fix it?

Comment: Your SD card/external storage spaces are not your internal app storage. You're looking at two completely different storage areas. Comparing those numbers is meaningless.

Comment: sdcard1 is internal storage no?

Comment: It's not *app* storage. It's internal media storage, for music/pictures/etc. Apps are not installed to `sdcard0` or `sdcard1`.

Answer (score 2):

Apps and their data are stored on a different partition (`/data`) from media (`/sdcard0`) and removable storage (`/sdcard1`).  If you are rooted, you can use an app like [Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) to check what's taking up space on your internal memory.

Comment: in my phone sd0 which is bigger is removable one...and sd1 is that stays with phone.

Comment: and whats a difference between disk usage app and storage analyser.

Comment: They have basically the same purpose, but you must understand that your phone storage is divided into lots of parts. The only part visible to you, as a normal user, is `sdcard1`. Apps are on a different partition (`data`).

Comment: ok i found data folder that you said is internal storage. So yea that is almost full...so how can i increase this partition.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Check some of the questions under the [tag:insufficient-memory] tag.  Some good advice there already.